# How to review an app from iTunes?

Tags: itunes

In iTunes I went to Library / Apps  and found the app but the only menu items are 'get info', 'show in windows explorer' and 'delete'. I want to write an review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the App in the iTunes store (OS X or iOS as appropriate) and then look for the stars to rate and then write a detailed review. You should be asked to sign in to your Apple ID and you must have purchased the app to write a review. If you received a gift or promotional copy, you might not be able to write a review in some cases.

[image: iTunes review section]

The **Write a Review** text is below the ScreenShots section so you may need to scroll the content up to see the link to submit a review.

Comment: It's a shame this is the only way to do so.  There really aren't enough options to link purchased content back to the store.  :-(

Comment: @Hand-E-Food I too would love to be able to make a review from my devices more directly, but it does make it easy for Apple to allow reviews only for the shipping version of an App - anything withdrawn or updated won't be visible from the actual App Store. It also helps them track when people try to make fake astroturf reviews and stuff the system with fake reviews.